# Desinstalar R (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: r, ubuntu

Estoy usando servidor con Ubuntu 16.04.5 para realizar algunas tareas bioinformáticas. Sin embargo, surgió un problema usando el paquete tximport de R, y al buscar algo de info, parece que puede ser culpa de la versión de este. La cosa es que instalé el 3.4.4 con apt-get pero al abrir R me aparece la versión 3.4.3. Incluso desinstalando r-base y r-base-core sigue apareciendo esta versión. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo podría eliminarlo o bien actualizarlo para que mi versión sea la 3.4.4?

Comment: Prueba primero a ver qué versión tienes instalada con apt-cache policy tximport. Puedes forzar una versión concreta con apt-get install tximport=3.4.4 siendo 3.4.4 (la parte detrás del =) la versión completa del paquete. También deberías poder especificar la versión a lanzar (en caso de tener instaladas más de una) con update-alternatives --list tximport

Comment: Por los números de versión imagino que estás hablando de R no de txtimport, es así? En los repositorios oficiales no suelen tener las últimas versiones. Lo que podrías hacer es bajarte el paquete deb de la versión que deseas (y luego lo instalas) desde la página de R: https://cran.r-project.org/ . Revisa "Download R for Linux"

Comment: Sí, hablo de la versión de R. Conseguí eliminar R del equipo y he instalado el 3.4.4, pero el problema ahora es que al ejecutarlo me aparece: Fatal error. Unable to open the base package. Creo que puede haber un error por culpa de que haya varias versiones de R instaladas (ciertos programas bioinformáticos por lo visto instalan la versión de R adecuada. Si no se soluciona reinstalaré todo el SO, aprovechando que aún no hay datos guardados.